# datetime2, norwegian day of week missing

Tags: datetime2

I have tried to figure out how to enable printing the day of week, but I cannot seem to be able to do this for norwegian. It works fine for British. I do realize that it might be because it is normally left out of dates in norwegian, but it should work when I force it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,norwegian]{article}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc]{datetime2}
\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2015-11-09}
\end{document}
```

Produces: 9. november 2015

```
\documentclass[11pt,british]{article}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc]{datetime2}
\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2015-11-09}
\end{document}
```

While this produces: Monday 9th November 2015

I need this to work for any given date, not just for today.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all language modules implement the `showdow` option. [datetime2-norsk](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-norsk) doesn't. For those of us who don't speak Norwegian, could you give some information as to how the day of week name should appear in dates, and maybe someone can provide a modified style.

Comment: I see from the datetime2-norsk documentation that it is not maintained anymore, and that there is a note to implement `showdow`in a future release. The weekdays are actually added for the `\DTMnorskWeekdayname` . Maybe somebody with the knowledge could write it in? In the meantime, I have made a hack that makes it work for my document, but it would be nice to have it working with the official one.

Comment: I asked for volunteers to help maintain the language modules, as unfortunately I don't have time to support them all. (There are [rather a lot of them](http://ctan.org/author/talbot).) I've had a few volunteers but no one for the datetime2-norsk module yet. Hopefully someone will step forward and implement it sometime soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a patched version of the `norsk` date style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,norwegian]{article}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc]{datetime2}

% undefine the norsk date style so \DTMnewdatestyle doesn't cause an error    
\csundef{@dtm@datestyle@norsk}

\DTMnewdatestyle{norsk}{%
   \renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{%
     \ifDTMshowdow
       \ifnum##4>-1
         \DTMnorskweekdayname{##4}%
         \space
       \fi
     \fi
     \DTMifbool{norsk}{showdayofmonth}
     {\DTMnorskordinal{##3}\DTMnorskdaymonthsep}%
     {}%
     \DTMnorskmonthname{##2}%
     \DTMifbool{norsk}{showyear}%
     {%
       \DTMnorskmonthyearsep
       \number##1
     }%
     {}%
   }%
   \renewcommand*\DTMDisplaydate[4]{%
     \ifDTMshowdow
       \ifnum##4>-1
         \DTMnorskWeekdayname{##4}%
         \space
       \fi
     \fi
     \DTMifbool{norsk}{showdayofmonth}
     {%
       \DTMnorskordinal{##3}\DTMnorskdaymonthsep
       \DTMnorskmonthname{##2}%
     }%
     {%
       \ifDTMshowdow
         \ifnum##4>-1
           \DTMnorskmonthname{##2}%
         \else
           \DTMnorskMonthname{##2}%
         \fi
       \else
          \DTMnorskMonthname{##2}%
       \fi
     }%
     \DTMifbool{norsk}{showyear}%
     {%
       \DTMnorskmonthyearsep
       \number##1
     }%
     {}%
   }%
}

\DTMsetdatestyle{norsk}

\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2015-11-09}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

mandag 9. november 2015

**Edit:**

I've just uploaded `datetime2` v1.2 to CTAN, which now allows you to redefine styles. It will probably take a few days to get into the distributions, but once it's available the `\csundef` hack won't be necessary and you can replace the lines:

```
% undefine the norsk date style so \DTMnewdatestyle doesn't cause an error    
\csundef{@dtm@datestyle@norsk}

\DTMnewdatestyle{norsk}{%
```

with just

```
\DTMrenewdatestyle{norsk}{%
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Hopefully somebody will take over the maintanance of your `date time2-norsk-package.

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple hack to make it work with a new command. This is not a good way to fix it, but it gets the job done until somebody edit the official Norwegian language module.

```
\documentclass[11pt,norwegian]{article}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dato}{sm} % hack to force day of week to be shown.
         {\DTMsavedate{datooo}{#2}\IfBooleanTF{#1}
           {\DTMnorskWeekdayname{\DTMfetchdow{datooo}} \DTMusedate{datooo}
           }
           {\DTMnorskweekdayname{\DTMfetchdow{datooo}} \DTMusedate{datooo}
           }
        }
\begin{document}
\dato{2015-11-09}
\dato*{2015-11-09}
\end{document}
```

Produces: 
mandag 9. november 2015 
Mandag 9. november 2015